# MembershipProvider persisting between tests

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I'm writing unit tests that involve creating a MembershipProvider and using it, and then tearing everything down and running a test using a *different and new provider*.

The issue is that the provider persists in memory and so the new provider's `Initialize(Initialize(string name, System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection config))` method is not called.

I've tried using reflection to clear all providers out of the `Membership.Providers` property but this does not work.

I've also tried manually calling `Initialize(..)` manually in`[TestInitialize]`:

```
NameValueCollection collection = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.web/membership") as NameValueCollection;
Membership.Provider.Initialize("defaultProvider", collection);
```

**EDIT**
Attempting some reflection...

```
 public static void Clear(MembershipProvider providerCollection) {

  Type t = typeof(Membership);
  FieldInfo providerCollectionReadOnlyField = t.GetField("Provider", BindingFlags.NonPublic);

  providerCollectionReadOnlyField.SetValue(null, null);
  bool prevValue = (bool)providerCollectionReadOnlyField.GetValue(providerCollection);

....
```

Comment: Could you use TestCleanup so that after your test runs you can do whatever cleanup you need?

Comment: I'm killing the DBs in the testcleanup, but the static membership provider is persisting. Do you know of a way to dispose of this too (it's also read-only)?

Comment: Does it have to be readonly? If not then try setting it to null and call GC.Collect() to force garbage collection

Comment: If the membership provider has to be readonly I wonder if you could set it to null using reflection... then call GC.Collect()

Comment: Yes that's what I'm trying but struggling to grab the Membership.Provider property with reflection.  I've posted my code above but providerCollectionReadOnlyField (excuse the naming!) is always null.